# When can I nuke someone?

Tags: civilization-board-game

[Civilization: The Board Game](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/77130/sid-meiers-civilization-the-board-game) (the 2010 version) has the *Atomic Theory* tech which lets me nuke someone.

> **Movement:** Nuke a non-capital city.  The city is destroyed, along
>   with all buildings, wonders, figures, and great people in its
>   outskirts.

Can I do this at any point during the movement phase of a turn, or can I only perform this action during **my** movement phase?

Comment: This tag always confuses me. Is this the Avalon Hill version, the FFG version, or some other version?

Comment: @user1873 Its the later (2010) FFG version

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only during your movement phase.

Page 22 or the rulebook, there is the card Currency :

> **City management** : Gain 3 culture tokens

and the following explanation :

> For example, Currency (shown above) allows a player to spend  one
>   incense resource token to gain three culture tokens during **the
>   player’s** City Management Phase